# Why do movies and series "leave" streaming services?

Tags: netflix, availability

I'd like to understand why services like Netflix or Amazon don't retain movies or series forever. That seems the logical thing to do: Potential revenue for basically zero extra effort, plus an ever-growing pool of awesome entertainment.

I can only imagine two reasons:

1. Somebody else offers more money for the license than can be generated by the streaming service. But how could that be so? Why would another streaming service be able to generate more money from it? Or do these films and series move to free TV? If the latter: Why not share the license? After all, apparently the audiences don't overlap much, so there is extra revenue to be had?
2. The expected revenue is less than the license fee plus storage cost for the movie, of which I'd think the license is the bulk. But doesn't that essentially mean that the license has become less valuable (because the movie or series has fallen out of fashion) and should be re-negotiated? After all — see point 1 — others are equally unlikely to generate beaucoup money from it now.

What is the typical reason to discontinue a movie or series?

P.S. I have trouble finding appropriate tags — no "license", "streaming", "amazon".... ah, "Netflix"! But the question is, while untypical, on topic, isn't it?

Comment: Sounds about right in my opinion. A series could be bought by other services for more money (eg Friends) or the service may only buy the licence to show it for X amount of time, but decide that it won't be worth renewing that licence due to viewing figures, for instance.

Comment: @user25730 The question of which this is a dup didn't show up when I edited this one, so I assumed it hadn't been asked before. My bad for not doing some research beforehand. I *still* wonder why some footage may generate more revenue somewhere else though, but I suppose it's different audiences, different gambles where public taste meanders etc.

Comment: _"Potential revenue for basically zero extra effort"_ You're forgetting the cost of licensing. The licensing cost is inhibitive, especially for things that are not watched enough to justify the cost.

Comment: _"free TV?"_ Barring some government channels, there is no such thing as free TV. It's either subscription based, ad-revenue based, or both. Ad-revenue based TV stations still have to pay the licensing fees.

Comment: _"But doesn't that essentially mean that the license has become less valuable (because the movie or series has fallen out of fashion) and should be re-negotiated?"_ The seller decides the cost of the license. No matter how much you can argue that they're charging too much, they can charge what they choose to charge.

Comment: @Flater "Free TV": No fee for the viewer.-- "they can charge what they choose to": Yes of course. But can they actually find a buyer for that asking price? If yes, somebody else can generate more revenue than the streaming service: The streaming service is doing something wrong. If not the asking price is a bad business decision, and the streaming service should convince them.